# Why does <h:link> change destination extension from .html to .xhtml?

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, facelets

I'm using JSF 2.1 and I'm experiencing some problems with the `<h:link>` tag.  I'm trying to have the link's outcome point from my XHTML file to a plain HTML file. However, when I run my web application, the `.html` extension in link's generated URL is automatically converted to a `.xhtml` extension.

Here is my Facelet file:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>        
        <h:link value="animation" outcome="#{contentForm.ccAnimationLink}"/>            
    </h:form>
<h:body>
```

Here is my contentForm bean:

```
package my.app.content;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ContentForm implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8463354828156798513L; 
    private String ccAnimationLink = "";    

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {        
        ccAnimationLink = "/content/cc/CC_animation/story.html";        
    }

    public String getCcAnimationLink() {
        return ccAnimationLink;
    }

    public void setCcAnimationLink(String ccAnimationLink) {
        this.ccAnimationLink = ccAnimationLink;
    }
}
```

Now, when I run this application, I get the following error:

> Unable to find matching navigation case from view ID '/content/modifiedcc.xhtml' for outcome '/content/cc/CC_animation/story.html'

I made sure that I had the URL correct, so I created a `story.xhtml` file in that location as well. With that file there it runs without errors.

If I pull the source for the generated page, I can see that the `<h:link>` was correctly changed to an "a href" tag, as follows:

```
<a href="/MyWebApp/content/cc/CC_animation/story.xhtml">animation</a>
```

For some reason though the URL changes from `story.html`, like I have it in my bean, to `story.xhtml`.

How can I make sure that it stays as story.html and not change it to xhtml?

Here is my `web.xml` file as well:

```
  <display-name>MyWebApp</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>jsf/login/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I tried adding the following to the `web.xml`, this didn't make a difference:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I'm sure this has a very simple solution which I'm just missing right now.  Help would be highly appreciated.  I hope the question is clear.

Comment: Is the file name `story.html` or `story.xhtml`?

Comment: @peeskillet - I want it to link to story.html, but my jsf is addament to link it to story.xhtml.  I created an empty story.xhtml file just so that I don't get errors, so that I can pull the source from the browser.  In a perfect world there shouldn't be a story.xhtml file.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work or not, but try adding another `<servlet-mapping>` element, mapping to url pettern `.*html`

Comment: @peeskillet - I tride that as well, didn't make a difference.  I've added that to my question above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSF 2.0+ has introduced [`<h:link>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) component that takes a navigation case outcome in its `outcome` attribute and *autogenerates the right URL on its own*. This is why you had the error without adding yet another mapping for the faces servlet: just reread the error. It is useful for creation of inter-JSF application navigation.

Alternatively, there has always been a [`<h:outputLink>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputLink.html) component that takes an URL in its `value` attribute instead. It is useful for creation of navigation external to a JSF application.

Be sure to read the classics from BalusC on the issue: [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink).

That said, consider the following components:

```
<h:link outcome="/destination" value="link" />
<h:outputLink value="/destination.html">
    outputLink
</h:outputLink>
```

The former component will translate its outcome into an actual URL, by appending a faces servlet mapping, while the latter one will leave its value as-is.

So, your problem will be solved by using the following component:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{contentForm.ccAnimationLink}">
    Animation
</h:outputLink>
```

Comment: Thank you!  You are my new favorite person! I would've given you an up vote on your answer, but apparently my reputation is too low to know what a good answer is :P

Comment: You're welcome! And thank you. One final piece of advice is to leave only one mapping for the faces servlet, `*.xhtml`, and remove the rest altogether.

Comment: You can also just use `<a href="#{contentForm.ccAnimationLink}">`.